# What can be fastest way to reach Heathrow Terminal 5 from Cambridge University?

Tags: airport-transfer, lhr, cambridge

I am leaving Fitzwilliam College of Cambridge University on Dec. 12, 5 pm, to Heathrow T5, in order to catch a flight departing at 9 pm.

What is the **fastest and most reliable** transportation? Taxi?

Comment: Check google maps; they tend to be reliable

Comment: Yes, but. I am worrying on traffic conditions, and train punctual issue.

Comment: then maybe a taxi would be worth it this ‘tis case

Comment: My flight is 9pm. Do you think I can catch it?

Comment: @RossTang Where are you flying to?  BA say check in at least one hour before for long haul and 45 minutes before for short haul.  Also where are you leaving from: Cambridge University is not a single place - it is scattered across the town.  The answer is probably different if you are on the New Museum site, or the West Cambridge site.

Comment: A taxi in a traffic jam is not faster than a delayed train but costs a LOT more.

Comment: @Willeke Taxis to London airports from Cambridge are usually fixed price.  (They charge extra in the other direction if the *plane* is delayed.)

Comment: I suspect helicopter would be the fastest. Not sure how reliable it is. And probably not affordable for most people.

Comment: I am thankful for every comment. I depart at Fitzwilliam College. What do you suggest?

Comment: Leaving at 5pm by taxi, you are likely to hit rush hour traffic on the M11 and M25. I’d suggest leaving an hour earlier if that’s at all possible.

Comment: `4 hrs` seems to be pushing it a bit. Stay off the roads on a working day, if possible. Get to King's cross by train, get down to Paddington and take the Heathrow express, if time seems short. Piccadily is one of the slowest of the tubes.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, note that the University of Cambridge is split over several sites across the city - it'll be important while planning your journey to ensure that you specify which faculty/college you'll be travelling from - in this case Fitzwilliam college.

There are three main potential routes, bus, taxi and train.

The main **railway station** is some way out of town, on the opposite side to Fitzwilliam College, and at that time of the evening it will not be a quick journey to get there by bus, foot or taxi. If you manage to get the train at 17:43, you can be at Terminal 5 by 19:50 with a change from the train to the Piccadily line tube at Kings Cross (travel via the Heathrow Express may shave a few minutes off the time, but not much). There are frequent trains every 10 minutes or so at that time of day to London, so the risk of a long delay is low, but you are cutting it fine to check in for a 21:00 flight.

There is a National Express **bus** at 17:30, that gets to the airport at 20:30. This looks like it would be too late to rely on, but gives an idea of the driving time that they can regularly schedule.

A **taxi** is almost certainly faster than the bus, due to flexibility over route, and not having to visit the intermediate stops (Stansted and other Heathrow terminals). It can also start as soon as you're ready, rather than waiting for the schedule. Google Maps predicts a time of 1:20 to 2:00 based on travel at 17:00 on a Wednesday. This fits with my limited experience.

Comment: Fitzwilliam College

Comment: On the Heathrow Express you should be able to make it by 19:32 on the 19:10 from Paddington, possibly even earlier if you make a quick getaway at King's Cross and manage to catch the 18:55 from Paddington. I agree that's still cutting it fine.

Comment: (I've asked another friend and he agrees catching the 18:55 from Paddington should be possible if you REALLY know what you're doing, and nothing is running late. So the 19:10 should be no problem).

Comment: Re "*The railway station*", there are now two. The other one is near the St John's Business Park, so it's still not very convenient for Fitz, but at least you can get there without going through the city centre. On the other hand, I don't think it has a very frequent service.

Comment: @PeterTaylor All of the fast trains stop at Cambridge North.

Answer (score 7):

I would **not** recommend the coach service, since, at that time of day, a coach can easily take 30–45 minutes just to get out of Cambridge (i.e.: before reaching the motorway).

A taxi all the way to the airport is an option, and would somewhat avoid the worst of the traffic in Cambridge (since Fitzwilliam is on the same side of Cambridge as the motorway). But, based on my own experience driving on the motorways themselves (both M11 and M25), they are likely to be congested (whenever I have driven the section of the M25 between Watford and Heathrow, there have been lower speed limits in place), so I suspect that a taxi would **not** be fastest.

So, your best bet is to travel by train, although getting to the principal railway station in Cambridge (CBG) would, unfortunately, entail traversing the city centre (as would getting to the coach station, by the way).

**To get from Fitzwilliam College to the principal railway station in Cambridge (CBG)**, the options, from fastest to slowest, are:

bicycle (if you can carry the luggage?!?);

taxi (expensive, but can get you through parts of the city centre where normal cars and minicabs cannot go);

minicab (cheaper than a taxi, but will have probably to go via the Fen Causeway and get stuck in traffic);

bus (at that time of day, there are regular buses towards the city centre from both Huntingdon Road and Madingley Road — I think there is a route on Madingley Road that goes directly to the railway station, whilst the routes on Huntingdon Road go only as far as the coach station)

**Once you are at Cambridge railway station (CBG)**, the fastest option is usually:

1. TRAIN Cambridge (CBG) --> London Kings Cross (KGX)
   *[do **not** get a train to Brighton via London St Pancras, since those trains stop at a lot of stations, and get overtaken by the ones to Kings Cross]*

   LONDON UNDERGROUND Kings Cross St Pancras --> Paddington
   *[i.e.: using EITHER **Circle** OR **Hammersmith & City** line westbound — they depart from the same platform, so just get the first train... if you find yourself on a Metropolitan line train, simply disembark at Euston Square or Great Portland Street, and wait on the platform for the next train of the correct line]*

   TRAIN London Paddington --> Heathrow Airport
   *[Heathrow Express is fastest, but hideously expensive; if time, use the slower TfL rail service]*

Alternative (cheaper, and with fewer interchanges, which may be an advantage if you have **lots** of luggage, but slower):

1. as above

   LONDON UNDERGROUND Kings Cross St Pancras --> Heathrow Airport
   *[i.e.: using the **Piccadilly** line... if you find yourself on a train to Uxbridge or Rayners Lane, simply disembark at or before Acton Town, and wait on the platform for the next train to Heathrow airport]*

Comment: I am very very grateful for so many useful suggestion. Let's do some research, and share my findings later.

Comment: Note that these suggestions according to the travelline planner take about 3 hours I would suggest you should leave earlier to meet check in time and allow for delays

Answer (score 6):

You've more choices. My son lives in the new NW Development, and I've looked at this issue for my own transport.

The [National Express website](https://nationalexpress.com) says that more runs are offered to LHR T2/T3 than to LHR T5, and the [LHR website](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/travel-between-terminals) says a traveler can easily transfer from T2/T3 to T5 on free LHR shuttle tains.

National Express lists these buses from Cambridge Parkside to LHR T2/T3 on December 12:

[image]

Even better (well, more direct but longer duration) for Fitzwilliam College, here are runs from the Madingley Park and Ride on the same date:

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the OP stated that he is only *leaving* FitzWilliam College at 5pm, would the answer still stand?

Comment: @B.Liu That's what he said, based on his research. I've given him more choices to make his flight at 9:00, including (in the first panel from National Express) a bus that leaves from Parkside later and arrives LHR earlier. The OP has choices.

Comment: I see your point. I (and possibly some other) did assume the 5pm was an at least semi-hard constraint and asked the question in the previous comment accordingly.

Comment: A particular comment on "a bus that leaves from Parkside later and arrives LHR earlier". If you are referring to the 17:30 coach, I believe that is an infeasible option as it only arrives at T2/3 at 19:55, and it takes at least 6 mins to take the rail transfer to T5, plus potentially up to 10m waiting time, plus walking. That would likely result in OP missing his flight if he got luggage to check-in, due to him missing the bag check cutoff. It doesn't invalidate your general answer based on your assumptions though.

Comment: Fitz to Parkside in 30 minutes in rush hour might be a bit tight by any means other than bike.